# Can't replace table name with variable in SQL query

Tags: php, sql

i've a little problem.
Here my request ( it work ):

```
 $reponse = $bdd->prepare('select * from student where UserName = ? and Password = ? ');
 $reponse->execute(array($name,$pass));
```

It's work but when i want to replace 'student' by a php variable it's doesn t works :/
Look :

```
 $table="stackoverflow"
 $reponse = $bdd->prepare('select * from '$table' where UserName = ? and Password = ? ');
 $reponse->execute(array($name,$pass));
```

Have you an idea ? It will be more simple if i can replace the table name by a variable.
sorry for my bad english.
Thanks you for the time you spend to me.

Comment: Please **do not** use `SELECT *` in your application, always write out each column name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, you join two strings or variables by a period character (.).

Therefore, to concatenate the table name and your statements before and after the table name, you should be changing this line

```
$reponse = $bdd->prepare('select * from '$table' where UserName = ? and Password = ? ');
```

To

```
$reponse = $bdd->prepare('select * from '.$table.' where UserName = ? and Password = ? ');
```

Answer (score 5):

Change this:

```
 $reponse = $bdd->prepare('select * from '$table' where UserName = ? and Password = ? ');
```

To:

```
 $reponse = $bdd->prepare("select * from `$table` where UserName = ? and Password = ? ");
```

Comment: this will not work if an identifier is wrapped with single quote. just `select * from $table where...`

Comment: Well, this will print:  select * from 'stackoverflow' where... and it will work...

Comment: Agree with you @JohnWoo

Answer (score 0):

Since the table name is a string, try-

```
"SELECT * FROM from \"".$table."\" WHERE ....... ";
```